# IDLE3 crash despite tkinter "correct" version

Tags: tkinter, python-idle

On macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, I have used Python3.7.1, installed *directly* from python.org, with biopython and used IDLE successfully, and happily, for some time.

Wanting to add a GUI, I used Homebrew to add PyGobject. This installs its own Python, and went to 3.7.2. The IDLE running from the HomeBrew install warns that I am using an unstable TCL/tk, despite [this page](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) saying Python3.7.x has an internal version of Tcl/tk to avoid this long-standing issue.

> >
>   Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 27 2018, 07:35:52) 
>   [Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>   WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable. Visit
>   http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.

It duly crashes when editing a file.

> >
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/bin/idle3", line 5, in 
>       main()
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 1569, in main
>       root.mainloop()
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1283, in mainloop
>       self.tk.mainloop(n)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Why does installing via Homebrew do this?

1. I have the PATH set to go via Homebrew, not the direct installation
2. PyGobject must be installed because the Hello World test produces a window
3. Biopython is installed & working
4. I set >>PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"< and >>PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/pkgconfig" as advised in the install-log
5. Other answers elsewhere say to install ActiveTCl - no joy, still crashes
6. PyCharm works , but ... not the issue really
7. I tried using JHbuild instead, but it's all built on Python2 and a trail of deprecated python2 __builtin__ commands etc to strip out

How do I get out of this please?

Comment: What happens when it crashes? Do you get an error? If so, what's the error?

Comment: Apologies for not including previously: - now added to question

Comment: The page you reference only says that installers from *python.org* include tcl/tk.  Apparently, Homebrew does not, so when you run Homebrew's 3.7.2., it does *not* use a 'correct' tcl/tk version.  (Take that up with Homebrew, if you want.) If you are going to stick with Homebrew's 3.7.2, follow the instructions to install tcl/tk 8.5.18 (or perhaps whatever Homebrew tells you to do).

Comment: Thanks. I did install the appropriate Tcl/tk, set the various PATH demands and tested the version. I have put the question up on the Homebrew site as suggested.

Comment: The warning is emitted by IDLE in idlelib.macosx after testing the result of 'import tkinter'.  So whatever you did with a newer tcl/tk, homebrew 3.7.2 does not import it.  I don't know if the instructions in .../mac/tcltk are supposed to work with Homebrew or not.